# Creating SSL Certificate in CMD, error popup

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

When I am trying to enter pbiviz command to create my SSL cert. It gives me an error everytime. I have an operating system of windows 7. I tried this on my workers laptop and it worked completely fine, and she has a windows 10. I deleted and reinstalled and still has not worked.

https://gyazo.com/acf03d87ffdfd8a5928446bfb2890508

Comment: Windows 7 isn't supported. Read the docs to resolve issue: https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/how-to-guide/create-ssl-certificate#generate-certificate-manually

Comment: installed openssll should be enough. --create-cert was merged with --install cert

Comment: Still Has not worked. It cant even realize the command "pbiviz --create-cert" but can for ""install--cert". Here is the error when I type in the command for "install-cert": error Certificate not found. The new certificate will be generated"

Comment: It is expected. Does dev server work after that?